# Is these algorithms equivalent?

Tags: algorithm, equivalent

E is a logic variable (T/F), P and Q are programs

```
(P)
If E then R
Else
S

(Q)
bool c  = E
bool d = not E
While  c do
    Begin
    R
    c = d
    End
While  d do
    Begin
    S
    d = c
    End
```

We knew that, the same input mean the same output, so they are weak-equivalency, but what about the execute time numbers (R)? I am not sure R is for (R,S) or E?

Answer (score 0):

As it is now, both variants are equivalent in the sense that R and S are fulfilled or not in both variants according to the same start conditions.

But the second variant also sets two variables c and d, and obviously they will be used somehow later, for otherwards there is no use in their setting inside while cycles. So, the second variant has additional and independent consequences (c and d are defined and set to false).

If the S and R can cancel the whole algorithm, that additional part becomes NOT independent.